# Sumas HTML sumar automáticamente campos vacío

Tags: javascript, html

Lo primero es decir que no tengo mucha idea de programación, me he metido a hacer una calculadora para una web y esto el lo mejor que puedo hacer. Necesitaría ayuda para.

1. Simplificar el script y que siga siendo funcional y
2. Conseguir que las distintas sumas totales se realicen sin tener que meter un valor.

Muchas gracias.

```js
function varios(){
n1 = parseInt(formulario.txt_num.value);
n2 = parseInt(formulario.txt_num2.value);
n3 = parseInt(formulario.txt_num3.value);
n4 = parseInt(formulario.txt_num4.value);
n5 = parseInt(formulario.txt_num5.value);   
n7 = parseInt(formulario.txt_num7.value);   
n8 = parseInt(formulario.txt_num8.value);   
n10 = parseInt(formulario.txt_num10.value);
n11 = parseInt(formulario.txt_num11.value);
n12 = parseInt(formulario.txt_num12.value);
n14 = parseInt(formulario.txt_num14.value);

formulario.txt_resultado.value=n1*242.25;
formulario.txt_resultado2.value=n2*327.25;
formulario.txt_resultado3.value=n3*412.25;
formulario.txt_resultado4.value=n4*497.25;  
formulario.txt_resultado5.value=n5*667.25;

formulario.txt_resultado6.value=(n1*242.25)+(n2*327.25)+(n3*412.25)+(n4*497.25)+(n5*667.25);

formulario.txt_resultado7.value=n7*228;
formulario.txt_resultado8.value=n8*156;

formulario.txt_resultado9.value=(n7*228)+(n8*156);

formulario.txt_resultado10.value=n10*497.25;
formulario.txt_resultado11.value=n11*228;
formulario.txt_resultado12.value=n12*175.5;

formulario.txt_resultado13.value=(n10*497.25)+(n11*228)+(n12*175.5);

formulario.txt_resultado14.value=n14*10;

formulario.txt_resultado15.value=(n1*242.25)+(n2*327.25)+(n3*412.25)+(n4*497.25)+(n5*667.25)+(n7*228)+(n8*156)+(n10*497.25)+(n11*228)+(n12*175.5)+(n14+10);

}
```

```html
<form name="formulario">
<tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td id="totales"><b>SESIONES</b></td>
            <td id="totales"><b>TOTAL DESCUENTO</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan=5><b>GRABACIÓN BASES</b></td>
<td><b>CONTROL B + SALA B</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" step="any" name="txt_num" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" step="any" name="txt_resultado" onkeyup="varios()"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><b>CONTROL B + SALA A</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_num2" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado2" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>CONTROL A + SALA A</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_num3" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado3" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>CONTROL B + SALA A</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_num4" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado4" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>CONTROL B + SALA A</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_num5" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado5" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr bgcolor="#F1c232"><td id="totales" colspan="3"><B>TOTAL BASES</b></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado6" size="20"  class="monto" onkeyup="varios()" /></td></tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2"><b>GRABACIÓN</br> RECORDINGS</b></td><td><b>ESTUDIO B</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" step="any" name="txt_num7" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" step="any" name="txt_resultado7" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>ESTUDIO C</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_num8" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado8" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr bgcolor="#F1c232"><td id="totales" colspan="3"><B>TOTAL RECORDINGS</b></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado9" size="20"  class="monto" onkeyup="varios()" /></td></tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan=3><b>MEZCLA</b></td>
<td><b>CONTROL A</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" step="any" name="txt_num10" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" step="any" name="txt_resultado10" size="20" onkeyup="varios()"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><b>CONTROL B</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_num11" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado11" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>CONTROL C</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_num12" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado12" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr bgcolor="#F1c232"><td id="totales" colspan="3"><B>TOTAL MEZCLAS</b></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado13" size="20"  class="monto" onkeyup="varios()" /></td></tr>
<tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td id="totales"><b>MINUTOS</b></td>
            <td id="totales"><b>TOTAL DESCUENTO</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2><b>MASTERING</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" step="any" name="txt_num14" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" step="any" name="txt_resultado14" size="20" onkeyup="varios()"></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#ff0000"><td id="totales" colspan="3"><h4><B>TOTAL</b></h4></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado15" size="20"  class="monto" onkeyup="varios()" /></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3"></td><td id="totales">
<input type="button" value="CALCULAR" onclick="varios()"></td></tr>
</form>
```

---

Pues en el ejemplo funciona pero en la web no me va y lo peor de todo es que no sabría decir por qué. Mando el código completo y el enlace por si puede servir de ayuda.
http://estudiouno.info/2514-2/
Muchísimas gracias por la respuesta de todas maneras.

```js
function extraerValor(val) {
  var result;
  if (val) {
    result = parseInt(val);
  } else {
    result = 0;
  }
  return result;
}
function varios(){
var n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n10, n11, n12, n13, n14;
n1 = parseInt(formulario.txt_num.value);
n2 = parseInt(formulario.txt_num2.value);
n3 = parseInt(formulario.txt_num3.value);
n4 = parseInt(formulario.txt_num4.value);
n5 = parseInt(formulario.txt_num5.value); 
n7 = parseInt(formulario.txt_num7.value); 
n8 = parseInt(formulario.txt_num8.value); 
n10 = parseInt(formulario.txt_num10.value);
n11 = parseInt(formulario.txt_num11.value);
n12 = parseInt(formulario.txt_num12.value);
n14 = parseInt(formulario.txt_num14.value);
 
formulario.txt_resultado.value=n1*242.25;
formulario.txt_resultado2.value=n2*327.25;
formulario.txt_resultado3.value=n3*412.25;
formulario.txt_resultado4.value=n4*497.25; 
formulario.txt_resultado5.value=n5*667.25;

formulario.txt_resultado6.value=(n1*242.25)+(n2*327.25)+(n3*412.25)+(n4*497.25)+(n5*667.25);

formulario.txt_resultado7.value=n7*228;
formulario.txt_resultado8.value=n8*156;
 
formulario.txt_resultado9.value=(n7*228)+(n8*156);

formulario.txt_resultado10.value=n10*497.25;
formulario.txt_resultado11.value=n11*228;
formulario.txt_resultado12.value=n12*175.5;
 
formulario.txt_resultado13.value=(n10*497.25)+(n11*228)+(n12*175.5);
 
formulario.txt_resultado14.value=n14*10;

formulario.txt_resultado15.value=(n1*242.25)+(n2*327.25)+(n3*412.25)+(n4*497.25)+(n5*667.25)+(n7*228)+(n8*156)+(n10*497.25)+(n11*228)+(n12*175.5)+(n14*10);

}
```

```html
<body>
<table width="75%" cellspacing="0" border="3" class="todo" bgcolor="#ffffff" bordercolor="#000000">
<form name="formulario">
<tr>
   <td colspan="2"></td>
   <td id="totales"><b>SESIONES</b></td>
   <td id="totales"><b>TOTAL DESCUENTO</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan=5><b>GRABACIÓN BASES</b></td>
<td><b>CONTROL B + SALA B</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" step="any" name="txt_num" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" step="any" name="txt_resultado" onkeyup="varios()"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><b>CONTROL B + SALA A</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_num2" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado2" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>CONTROL A + SALA A</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_num3" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado3" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>CONTROL B + SALA A</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_num4" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado4" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>CONTROL B + SALA A</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_num5" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado5" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr bgcolor="#F1c232"><td id="totales" colspan="3"><B>TOTAL BASES</b></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado6" size="20"  class="monto" onkeyup="varios()" /></td></tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2"><b>GRABACIÓN</br> RECORDINGS</b></td><td><b>ESTUDIO B</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" step="any" name="txt_num7" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" step="any" name="txt_resultado7" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>ESTUDIO C</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_num8" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado8" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr bgcolor="#F1c232"><td id="totales" colspan="3"><B>TOTAL RECORDINGS</b></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado9" size="20"  class="monto" onkeyup="varios()" /></td></tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan=3><b>MEZCLA</b></td>
<td><b>CONTROL A</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" step="any" name="txt_num10" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" step="any" name="txt_resultado10" size="20" onkeyup="varios()"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><b>CONTROL B</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_num11" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado11" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>CONTROL C</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_num12" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado12" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr bgcolor="#F1c232"><td id="totales" colspan="3"><B>TOTAL MEZCLAS</b></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado13" size="20"  class="monto" onkeyup="varios()" /></td></tr>
<tr>
   <td colspan="2"></td>
   <td id="totales"><b>MINUTOS</b></td>
   <td id="totales"><b>TOTAL DESCUENTO</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2><b>MASTERING</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" step="any" name="txt_num14" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" step="any" name="txt_resultado14" size="20" onkeyup="varios()"></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#ff0000"><td id="totales" colspan="3"><h4><B>TOTAL</b></h4></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado15" size="20"  class="monto" onkeyup="varios()" /></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3"></td><td id="totales">
<input type="button" value="CALCULAR" onclick="varios()"></td></tr>
</form>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sencilla de hacerlo sería considerar que, cuando el valor de la *cantidad* no ha sido ingresado, es cero.

Para ello, he hecho una función `extraerValor` que tiene esa lógica, y luego he sustituido las llamadas a `parseInt` por esta nueva función. El resto del *script* no ha sido modificado.

```js
function extraerValor(val) {
  var result;
  if (val) {
    result = parseInt(val);
  } else {
    result = 0;
  }
  return result;
}

function varios(){
  var n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n10, n11, n12, n13, n14;
  n1 = extraerValor(formulario.txt_num.value);
  n2 = extraerValor(formulario.txt_num2.value);
  n3 = extraerValor(formulario.txt_num3.value);
  n4 = extraerValor(formulario.txt_num4.value);
  n5 = extraerValor(formulario.txt_num5.value);   
  n7 = extraerValor(formulario.txt_num7.value);   
  n8 = extraerValor(formulario.txt_num8.value);   
  n10 = extraerValor(formulario.txt_num10.value);
  n11 = extraerValor(formulario.txt_num11.value);
  n12 = extraerValor(formulario.txt_num12.value);
  n14 = extraerValor(formulario.txt_num14.value);

  formulario.txt_resultado.value=n1*242.25;
  formulario.txt_resultado2.value=n2*327.25;
  formulario.txt_resultado3.value=n3*412.25;
  formulario.txt_resultado4.value=n4*497.25;  
  formulario.txt_resultado5.value=n5*667.25;

  formulario.txt_resultado6.value=(n1*242.25)+(n2*327.25)+(n3*412.25)+(n4*497.25)+(n5*667.25);

  formulario.txt_resultado7.value=n7*228;
  formulario.txt_resultado8.value=n8*156;

  formulario.txt_resultado9.value=(n7*228)+(n8*156);

  formulario.txt_resultado10.value=n10*497.25;
  formulario.txt_resultado11.value=n11*228;
  formulario.txt_resultado12.value=n12*175.5;

  formulario.txt_resultado13.value=(n10*497.25)+(n11*228)+(n12*175.5);

  formulario.txt_resultado14.value=n14*10;

  formulario.txt_resultado15.value=(n1*242.25)+(n2*327.25)+(n3*412.25)+(n4*497.25)+(n5*667.25)+(n7*228)+(n8*156)+(n10*497.25)+(n11*228)+(n12*175.5)+(n14+10);

}
```

```html
<form name="formulario">
<tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td id="totales"><b>SESIONES</b></td>
            <td id="totales"><b>TOTAL DESCUENTO</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan=5><b>GRABACIÓN BASES</b></td>
<td><b>CONTROL B + SALA B</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" step="any" name="txt_num" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" step="any" name="txt_resultado" onkeyup="varios()"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><b>CONTROL B + SALA A</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_num2" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado2" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>CONTROL A + SALA A</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_num3" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado3" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>CONTROL B + SALA A</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_num4" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado4" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>CONTROL B + SALA A</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_num5" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado5" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr bgcolor="#F1c232"><td id="totales" colspan="3"><B>TOTAL BASES</b></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado6" size="20"  class="monto" onkeyup="varios()" /></td></tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2"><b>GRABACIÓN</br> RECORDINGS</b></td><td><b>ESTUDIO B</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" step="any" name="txt_num7" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" step="any" name="txt_resultado7" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>ESTUDIO C</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_num8" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado8" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr bgcolor="#F1c232"><td id="totales" colspan="3"><B>TOTAL RECORDINGS</b></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado9" size="20"  class="monto" onkeyup="varios()" /></td></tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan=3><b>MEZCLA</b></td>
<td><b>CONTROL A</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" step="any" name="txt_num10" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" step="any" name="txt_resultado10" size="20" onkeyup="varios()"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><b>CONTROL B</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_num11" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado11" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>CONTROL C</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_num12" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado12" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr bgcolor="#F1c232"><td id="totales" colspan="3"><B>TOTAL MEZCLAS</b></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado13" size="20"  class="monto" onkeyup="varios()" /></td></tr>
<tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td id="totales"><b>MINUTOS</b></td>
            <td id="totales"><b>TOTAL DESCUENTO</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2><b>MASTERING</b></td>
<td id="totales"><input type="number" step="any" name="txt_num14" class="todo" onkeyup="varios()" /></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" step="any" name="txt_resultado14" size="20" onkeyup="varios()"></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#ff0000"><td id="totales" colspan="3"><h4><B>TOTAL</b></h4></td><td id="totales"><input type="number" name="txt_resultado15" size="20"  class="monto" onkeyup="varios()" /></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3"></td><td id="totales">
<input type="button" value="CALCULAR" onclick="varios()"></td></tr>
</form>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda. Es lo que buscaba, lo que pasa es que no copié bien la respuesta.